# Dividing an array into equally weighted subarrays

Tags: ruby, algorithm

Algorithm question here.

I have an unordered array containing product weights, e.g. `[3, 2, 5, 5, 8]` which need to be divided up into smaller arrays.

Rules:

- **REQUIRED**: Should return 1 or more arrays.
- **REQUIRED**: No array should sum to more than 12.
- **REQUIRED**: Return minimum possible number of arrays, ex. total weight of example above is 23, which can fit into two arrays.
- **IDEALLY**: Arrays should be weighted as evenly as possible.

In the example above, the ideal return would be `[ [3, 8], [2, 5, 5] ]`

My current thoughts:

- Number of arrays to return will be `(sum(input_array) / 12).ceil`
- A [greedy algorithm](http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/greedy-algorithm) could work well enough?

Comment: haha `array.each_slice(1).to_a` all under 12 (if the last rule is not important)  :). Might want to rethink the rules. Also wouldn't the ideal be `[[3,5],[8],[2,5]]` as the weighting here seems more even to me?

Comment: @engineersmnky thanks for your input - added a fourth rule above to clarify why `[ [3, 8], [2, 5, 5] ]` is better than `[ [3, 5], [8], [2, 5] ]`

Comment: I think that if you could solve this, you could solve subset sum, which is NP-Complete http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: @davidrac haha I saw that subset sum problem is NP-Complete during my initial approach to this problem. My solution doesn't need to be perfect, just serviceable. That's why I was considering a greedy algorithm, iterating through up the initial array one-by-one and moving into the best position in the return arrays. That would inevitably sometimes result in imperfectly balanced return arrays, but that's not the end of the world.

Comment: Isn't this a form of the [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)?

Comment: Aside from the similarities with several NP-complete problems, the problem does not seem well-defined. You want both the minimum possible number of arrays and the most evenly weighted arrays, but what if a more evenly weighted solution involves more arrays or vice versa?

Comment: @tadman thanks for the resource, that's very similar.

Comment: @Max minimum number of arrays trumps evenly weighted. Solution must use minimum possible number of arrays, and balance the weights throughout those as evenly as possible.

Comment: Sam, when you have dual objectives to be optimized, you have several choices: 1) create a single objective (e.g., a weighted average of the number of arrays and some measure of size deviation); 2) optimize one of the objectives subject constraints related to the value of the other objective; 3) compute an "efficient frontier", which are solutions that are not "dominated" by other solutions (e.g., if minimizing, a solution with values for the two objectives of `[u1,2]` where there is not another solution with values `[v1,v2]` for which `v1 <= u1`, `v2 <= u2` and `v1+v2 < u1+u2)`; (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) and 4) optimize for one objective and then optimize for the second objective subject to constraints related to the first optimized solution (e.g., minimize the number of sets, finding that number to be `n`, then minimize some measure of size deviations subject to the requirement that there be `n` sets. It appears you are opting for #4, which I think is sensible. In that case you have two problems rather than one.  I suggest you limit this question to the first. Even that problem is NP-complete. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) You can ask for an optimal solution, but I don't think it's appropriate to ask for heuristic solutions, as there is no way to evaluate them.

Comment: @tadman, unfortunately, this problem this is not a knapsack problem.  For the later there is a single state variable, which is the amount of room left in the knapsack after some goods have been added.  The idea is that *if* there are `v` cubic meters of space left after some items have been added (`v` being the state variable), the optimal way of filling the remaining space is independent of what's already in the bag ("Principle of Optimality").  A function `f(n,v)` is built which is the optimal value of what's in the bag at "stage `n`", *given* `v` is the amount of space left. (cont.)

Comment: (cont.) For each `n`, `f(n,v)` is computed for all possible values of `v`. In the present problem, after some elements of the array have been added to subarrays, the state variable is a vector whose elements are the totals for each of the subarrays. You can imaging that the number of possible values for the state variable gets very large very fast.

Answer (score 2):

This is a combination of the [bin packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem) and [multiprocessor scheduling problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiprocessor_scheduling). Both are NP-hard.

Your three requirements constitute the bin packing problem: find the minimal number of bins of a fixed size (12) that fit all the numbers.

Once you solve that, you have the multiprocessor scheduling problem: given a fixed number of bins, what is the most even way to distribute the numbers among them.

There are number of well-known approximate algorithms for both problems.

Answer (score 0):

How about something with an entirely different take on it. Something really simple. Like this, which is based on common horse sense:

```ruby
module Splitter

    def self.split(values, max_length = 12)

        # if the sum of all values is lower than the max_length there
        # is no point in continuing
        return values unless self.sum(values) > max_length

        optimized = []
        current = []

        # start off by ordering the values. perhaps it's a good idea
        # to start off with the smallest values first; this will result
        # in gathering as much values as possible in the first array. This
        # in order to  conform to the rule "Should return minimum possible 
        # number of arrays"
        ordered_values = values.sort

        ordered_values.each do |v|

            if self.sum(current) + v > max_length

                # finish up the current iteration if we've got an optimized pair
                optimized.push(current)

                # reset for the next iteration
                current = []
            end

            current.push(v)
        end

        # push the last iteration
        optimized.push(current)

        return optimized
    end

    # calculates the sum of a collection of numbers
    def self.sum(numbers)
        if numbers.empty?
            return 0
        else
            return numbers.inject{|sum,x| sum + x }
        end
    end
end
```

Which can be used like so:

```rb
product_weights = [3, 2, 5, 5, 8]
p Splitter.split(product_weights)
```

The output will be:

> [[2, 3, 5], [5], [8]]

Now, as said before, this is a really simple sample. And I've excluded the validations for empty or non-numeric values in the array for brevity. But it does seem to conform to your primary requirements:

- Splitting the (expected: all numeric) values into arrays
- With a ceiling per array, defaulting in the sample to 12
- <strike>Return minimum amount of arrays by collection the smallest numbers first</strike> **EDIT:** after the edit from the comments, this indeed doesn't work

I do have some doubts regarding the comment on "returning minimum possible number of arrays, and balance the weights throughout those as evenly as possible". I'm sure someone else will come up with an implementation of a better and math-proven algorithm that conforms to that requirement, but perhaps this is at least a suitable example for the discussion?

Comment: you realize your output does not match the expectations correct? Array[0] has a sum of 15.

Comment: @engineersmnky ouch... you're right. I've corrected the sample and updated the outcome, resulting in not fulfilling all requirements anymore. Sorry, should not have overlooked that.